# How to Fix -- Jenkins Post-build Action Groovy script fails to evaluate

Tags: jenkins, groovy, post-build

I'm new to Groovy and am trying to invoke a Groovy script as a Jenkins Post-build Action, but whenever I run it, I'm getting "ERROR: Failed to evaluate groovy script":

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.stage() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [branch_1, Script1$_run_closure1@7e39737b] 
>   Possible solutions: wait(), any(), isCase(java.lang.Object) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)

Here is my code :

```
def warList1= ["one.war", "two.war", "three.war" ]

def branches = [:] 

for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    int index=i, branch = i+1
        stage ("branch_${branch}"){
            branches["branch_${branch}"] = { 
                node {
                    sshagent(credentials : ['someuser-SSH']){
                        sh "scp ${WORKSPACE}/${warList1[index]} someuser@<somefqdn>:/tmp/pscp/dev"
                    }
                }     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information ? Like the configuration of the post build action (with the Groovy Posybuild Plugin I presume) and the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.stage() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [branch_1, Script1$_run_closure1@7e39737b]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), isCase(java.lang.Object)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)

Comment: Please edit the question instead of putting further informations in comments.

Comment: The same global vars are not available, I don't use pipeline so I cannot test but you probably need to do something like ```import hudson.model.*``` and maybe ```def build = Thread.currentThread().executable``` or get the stage/branches/node/sshagent objects from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your issue come from the fact that you can not use `stage` method in a Groovy Post Build Action. This method is only available in a pipeline script.